# Python Tkinter Multiple buttons are getting created on clicking on radio buttons

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

These are few lines from my actual code - I am aware this is not the best way of writing a code, but as I am new and getting familiarize with Tkinter (py2) consider this as my scratch work.

I am listing a question and multiple options. When the user selects an option, a SUBMIT button is created and when clicks on SUBMIT button it will accordingly change the color of Option to green or red. If green then another NEXT button will be available to clean and move to next question.

The issue that I am facing is if a user selects option A but then **without clicking the SUBMIT button** selects another option the submit button multiplies. I want to destroy the unwanted buttons or even do not want to create multiple SUBMIT buttons.
Please do help in achieving the same.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import yaml
import random

grey = "#808080"
offwhite = "#e3e3e3"

filepath = "chapter-2.yaml"


tk = Tkinter.Tk()
tk.title("iCodet Learnings")
tk.geometry("800x600")

x = ''
tk.config(background=offwhite)
tk.resizable(0,0)
q_count = 0

def yaml_loader(filepath):
    with open (filepath, "r") as fileread:
        data = yaml.load(fileread)
        return data

def cleaner(hint):
    global rbutton
    global q_count
    global quest_label
    global radio1
    global button_game
    quest_label.destroy()
    radio1.destroy()
    # destroys the radio buttons
    for b in rbutton:
        b.destroy()
    # destroys the SUBMIT button
    button_game.destroy()
    # go to ext question
    if hint == 'next':
        q_count += 1
        game_loop()


# This is display the first element from the yaml i.e the question
def display_question(questions, qc):
    global quest_label
    q = questions.keys()[qc]
    a = questions[q]
    v = a.keys()
    quest_label = Label(tk, text = q, font = ("Consolas", 16), width = 500, justify = "center", wraplength = 400)
    quest_label.pack(pady = (50,0))
    return v

# This is for selecting the radio buttons
def selected():
    global radio_default, button_next,radio1, val
    global x, data,q_count, vali, rbutton, select_val
    x = radio_default.get()
    select_val =  rbutton[x]
    if q_count <= len(data):
        q = data.keys()[q_count]
        a = data[q]  #second dictionary
        v = a.keys() #second dictionary keys
        # True or False from Yaml
        val = a[v[x]][0]
        press_button(val)
    else:
        print ("Mid way")

# This will list all the options under question
def display_answer(ans):
    global radio1, rbutton
    global x, q_count
    global radio_default
    radio_default = IntVar()
    rbutton = []
    rad_select = []
    val_count = 0
    for i in ans:
        radio1 = Radiobutton(tk, text = i, font = ("times", 14, "bold"), value = val_count, variable = radio_default, command = selected, background = 'NavajoWhite3')
        rbutton.append(radio1)
        val_count += 1
        radio1.pack(pady = (30,0))
        radio_default.set(-1)

# This displays the SUBMIT buuton
def press_button(val):
    global button_game
    # true
    if val:
        button_game = Button(tk, text = 'SUBMIT', font = ("default", 15, "bold"), bg='orange', fg = 'white', border=2, height = 2, width = 8, command = lambda: cleaner('next'))
        button_game.pack(pady = (30,0))
    # false
    elif not val:
        print "Do nothing"
        button_game = Button(tk, text = 'SUBMIT', font = ("default", 15, "bold"), bg='orange', fg = 'white', border=2, height = 2, width = 8, command = lambda: cleaner('stay'))
        button_game.pack(pady = (30,0))
    return True

def game_loop():
    global q_count
    global x, data
    global quest_label, button_game
    action = True
    data = yaml_loader(filepath)
    if q_count <= len(data)-1:
        l_ans = display_question(data, q_count)
        display_answer(l_ans)
    else:
        txt_label = Label(tk, text = "CONGRATULATIONS ON COMPLETING CHAPTER", font = ("Comicsans", 24, "bold"), background = offwhite, wraplength = 700)
        txt_label.pack(pady = (100,0))

        button_end = Button(tk, text = 'THANK YOU !', font = ("default", 15, "bold"), bg='saddle brown', fg = 'white', border=2, height = 3, width = 10, command = tk.destroy)
        button_end.pack(pady = (50,0))

game_loop()
tk.mainloop()
```

chapter-1.yaml

```
> "What’s the complete name of Sachin Tendulkar ?":
>                 "Sachin Ramya Tendulkar":
>                         - False
>                 "Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar":
>                         - True
>                 "Sachin Tendehar":
>                         - False
>                 " Sachin 10dulkar":
>                         - False
>                 "Hint":
>                         - "biscuit & cookies"
```

Comment: What's the content of `chapter-1.yaml`?Could you show it?

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of code that isn't relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA  I have added a snippet of yaml file that I am using.

Comment: @BryanOakley Hi I have edited the code just to focus on the actual issue. Issue: Click option A, Click option B now we have 2 submit buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I was looking for with the help of **config**.
I created the SUBMIT button once at the beginning and then instead of calling the whole function again and again; I just replaced press_button with `button_game.config(command = lambda: right(chapter, num_ques, topic, val))`

Now I should write this code using class in python.

Answer (score 1):

As things are, each time `press_button()` is run, a new `Button` object is generated, and placed in the `button_game` variable. This does not remove or hide the previous button, which still exists in the packed UI.

A simple solution that would save the machine some work is to initialize the button only once, earlier in the code, but omit placing/displaying/packing it until that block within `press_button()` is run.